# For Amazon Connect live audio streams, is agent track always 2, and customer track always 1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

Following [Amazon's example](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-realtime-transcription) for reading live audio chunks out of Amazon Connect,
I have logic like this:

```
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public enum TrackName {
        // Track #s: (1) for "customer" or "inbound"; (2) for "agent" or "outbound".
        AUDIO_FROM_CUSTOMER("AUDIO_FROM_CUSTOMER", 1),
        AUDIO_TO_CUSTOMER("AUDIO_TO_CUSTOMER", 2);

        @Getter
        private final String name;

        @Getter final long trackNum;
    }

    ...

    public static AudioChunkTrack getByteBufferFromStream(StreamingMkvReader streamingMkvReader,
                                                          FragmentMetadataVisitor fragmentVisitor,
                                                          KVSContactTagProcessor tagProcessor) throws MkvElementVisitException {
        while (streamingMkvReader.mightHaveNext()) {
            Optional<MkvElement> mkvElementOptional = streamingMkvReader.nextIfAvailable();
            if (mkvElementOptional.isPresent()) {
                if (tagProcessor.shouldStopProcessing()) {
                    return new AudioChunkTrack(ByteBuffer.allocate(0), null, -1);
                }
                MkvElement mkvElement = mkvElementOptional.get();
                mkvElement.accept(fragmentVisitor);
                log.trace("processing element {}", mkvElement.getElementMetaData().getTypeInfo());
                if (MkvTypeInfos.SIMPLEBLOCK.equals(mkvElement.getElementMetaData().getTypeInfo())) {
                    MkvDataElement dataElement = (MkvDataElement) mkvElement;
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Frame frame = ((MkvValue<Frame>) dataElement.getValueCopy()).getVal();
                    ByteBuffer audioBuffer = frame.getFrameData();

                    long trackNumber = frame.getTrackNumber();
                    MkvTrackMetadata metadata = fragmentVisitor.getMkvTrackMetadata(trackNumber);
                    return new AudioChunkTrack(audioBuffer, metadata.getTrackName(), trackNumber);
                }
            }
        }

        return new AudioChunkTrack(ByteBuffer.allocate(0), null, -1);
    }
```

Here, `trackNumber` is always 1 (with metadata tag `AUDIO_FROM_CUSTOMER`) or 2 (with metadata tag `AUDIO_TO_CUSTOMER`).

Can I assume that track #2 is for the Agent channel, and track #1 the Customer channel (ie, the caller)?

I am seeing some results that suggest this assumption may not always be true.  If it is not true, is there some way in Amazon Connect that I can hardwire the alignment of track # with Agent/Customer label?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about track numbers, but agent is always recorded on the right channel. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/set-up-recordings.html):

> The agent audio is stored in the right channel. All incoming audio, including the customer and anyone conferenced in, is stored in the left channel.

Comment: That helps.  But as you indicated, it does not say how Amazon Connect tags the real-time audio chunks.  Something may be amiss; in particular, I am seeing inconsistent tagging *across* conversations -- in one conversation, 1 is customer and 2 agent, while in a different conversation 2 is customer and 1 agent.